# Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies.

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I downloaded the web app from my company's server and running it on my machine. It works well except when I click on one of the menu items (all the others are good). It is showing me this error. I checked my web.config and the version I set for web.mvc is 4.0.0.0. I have no idea how is this happen.

I checked the similar problem on the websites but the solutions are not working for me. Here is the assembly load trace info that might be helpful:

Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to determine why the assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' could not be loaded.

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///%working root%/WebApplication/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = %working root%\WebApplication\bin

## Calling assembly : App_Web_e4sj14ak, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.

LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: %working root%\WebApplication\web.config
LOG: Using host configuration file: C:\Users\Kevin\Documents\IISExpress\config\aspnet.config
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Post-policy reference: System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/Kevin/AppData/Local/Temp/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/57d1caa4/e98fbd78/System.Web.Mvc.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/Kevin/AppData/Local/Temp/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/57d1caa4/e98fbd78/System.Web.Mvc/System.Web.Mvc.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///%working root%/WebApplication/bin/System.Web.Mvc.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///%working root%/WebApplication/bin/System.Web.Mvc/System.Web.Mvc.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/Kevin/AppData/Local/Temp/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/57d1caa4/e98fbd78/System.Web.Mvc.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/Kevin/AppData/Local/Temp/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/57d1caa4/e98fbd78/System.Web.Mvc/System.Web.Mvc.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///%working root%/WebApplication/bin/System.Web.Mvc.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///%working root%/WebApplication/bin/System.Web.Mvc/System.Web.Mvc.EXE.

I am really confused that I am using MVC4 but the error message is version of 3.0.0.0. This problem has annoyed me for a long time. Please help me and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved by installing MVC 3.0 in my computer. Now it's working.

Answer (score 0):

On your web.config, be sure to have this inside `assemblyBinding` section

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

It forces to use 4.0.0.0 no matter what assembly version is trying to bind

Comment: Thanks for replying. 
Ye, I have got these code in my web.config but it keeps showing me the error.

Comment: @Kevin W:Delete all temporal files generated and call "rebuild solution" to see if that fixes it

Comment: how to find the temporal files in the project?

Comment: @KevinW: it should be something like this `C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\`. Inside that folder there should be a folder for your web site

Comment: I checked the folder. Its empty.